# e-commerce product load by react redux and redux-thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux, e-commerce, redux-thunk

I am doing an e-commerce website with react, redux, redux-thunk ( I don't know redux-thunk yet ). Let's say the website has **6-page** Homepage, Shop Page, and Contact page, about page, Order page, checkout page, and if we click on the product it will show the product details page.

In **Homepage** there are 3 different slider which needs all the product to show in sliders that means I need have all the products from API in homepage.

also, On **shop page** I need to show all the products on *Shop page*

I have a component named **Layout** inside where I conditionally render pages like for / Homepage will be loaded and /shop shop-page will be loaded. then I import the Layout component in the Appjs file.

App.js

```
    

    import React from 'react';
    import './App.module.css';
    import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
    import Layout from './container/layout/Layout.js'
    import HomePage from './Pages/HomePage/HomePage';
    import ShopPage from './Pages/ShopPage/ShopPage';
    import SingleRroductPage from './Pages/SingleProductPage/SingleRroductPage';
    
    
    
    function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <Layout>
    
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage} /> 
              <Route path="/shop" component={ShopPage} />
              <Route path="/single/:id" component={SingleRroductPage} />
            </Switch>
          </Layout>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Layout.js

```
    

    import React from 'react';
    
    import Topbar from '../../component/header/topbar/Topbar';
    import Footer from '../Footer/Footer';
    import Navbar from '../navbar/Navbar';
    
    
    
    
    function Layout(props) {
    
        return (
            <div>
                <Topbar />
                <Navbar />
                {props.children}
                <Footer/>
            </div>
        );
    }
    
    export default Layout;
```

Now the question is where should I load the products from API?

-In Appjs?
-Separately on both the Homepage and Shop page?
-In layoutjs file?

if I load all the products in App.js or Layout.js file then all the products will be on every other page like contact and about pages. it wouldn't be a performance issue?

**For product details page**

should I use a different API endpoint like

`` "/api/products/single:id" ? ```
or from all product filter by id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each component should be responsible for requesting its own data.  `HomePage` and `ShopPage` should both call an action to load the data that they need (in an ideal setup, that action will check if the data already exists in the state before fetching, but that's getting ahead of ourselves).

Of course you don't want to be repeating logic for every component that needs to fetch data.  That's where redux comes to the rescue.  You can define an action creator `fetchApiData(endpoint)` which takes the name of the endpoint that you want to call.  All of the logic associated with fetching and storing the data is handled in your redux files (often called `reducer.js`, `actions.js`, etc.).

Your components are responsible for:

- calling the `fetchApiData(endpoint)` function once per endpoint when the component is mounted
- using a selector function to get the products that they need from the store
- displaying the products

Answer (score 0):

Redux provides you the store that can be used in any component.
You can call the API from app.js
and if you update the store you can re-use the data from 1 API call.